# JDBC: How can I query by time in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have this JDBC SQL query:

```
select *
from table
where TX_DATE = {d '2009-01-05'} and TX_TIME = {t '15:23:39'}
```

This returns some rows. Note that, since Oracle has no TIME type, both columns are of type DATE.

But it fails when I use JDBC parameters:

```
select *
from table
where TX_DATE = ? and TX_TIME = ?
```

where the first parameter is `new java.sql.Date(...)` and the second is `new java.sql.Time(...)`. I print both parameters to stdout and they look good, so the values are correct. But I don't get any rows. Why? What's different between `{t '15:23:39'}` and `new java.sql.Time()`?

[EDIT] Here is the code that fills the `PreparedStatement`:

```
public static void setParameters (final PreparedStatement stmt,
        final Object... param)
{
    for (int i=0; i<param.length; i++)
    {
        Object debug = param[i];
        String type = null;

        if (param[i] == null)
            stmt.setString(i+1, null);
        else if (param[i] instanceof java.sql.Time)
             stmt.setTime (i+1, (java.sql.Time)param[i]);
```

I've set a breakpoint in `setTime()` and it gets called. `param[1].toString()` prints `15:23:39`, so I know the value is correct.

My guess is that since Oracle doesn't have a TIME type, there is a bug in the driver and the DATE part of the time is not ignored.

If I use `select *` on the whole table, I get

```
TX_DATE     TX_TIME
2009-01-08  2009-08-01
```

As you can seem, the time column is treated like a date by default. If I use `TO_CHAR(TX_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS')`, I get:

```
TX_DATE     TX_TIME
2009-01-08  15:23:39
```

Where does `2009-08-01` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does not have a Java type for time. The java.sql.Time class is mapped to the oracle.sql.DATE class, even in the latest drivers. [Documentation Here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/datacc.htm#g1028145) What you should do is have the "day" portion of TX_TIME be some standard value (say 1970-01-01). Then you can query on this column with a static "day" and have the time work as expected.

Depending upon what version of the Oracle drivers you're using, the handling of java.sql.Date and java.sql.Timestamp for an Oracle DATE column type is different. Check the [JDBC FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_faq.html) for more info. Good luck!

```
public static void setParameters (final PreparedStatement stmt,
    final Object... param)
{
  for (int i=0; i<param.length; i++)
  {
      Object debug = param[i];
      String type = null;

      if (param[i] == null)
        stmt.setString(i+1, null);
      else if (param[i] instanceof java.sql.Time) 
      {
        stmt.setTime (
          i+1, 
          java.sql.Timestamp.valueof("1970-01-01 " + param[i] + ".000000000")
         );
      }
```

Comment: Thanks; I was somehow expecting that Oracle would use the same "day" part if I didn't specify one instead of "1st of the current month".

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a `PreparedStatement` in this?

```
PrepapredStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
               "select * from table where TX_DATE = ? and TX_TIME = ?")
stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime));
stmt.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(myDate.getTime));

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: As I wrote, I'm using java.sql.Time, not java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: I'm initializing the time with a SimpleDateFormat.parse() with the format "HH:mm:ss" and the value "15:23:39".

Comment: Can you post yuour *actual code*. It's difficult to debug code which I can't see! Are you using `PreparedStatement` and saetting the parameters as I said (albeit with a time)? Have you tried using a timestamp instead, or just used the date bit to see if that worked?

Comment: See my edit; my guess is that there is a bug in the Oracle driver due to the fact that Oracle doesn't have a real "TIME" type.

Comment: Note that the type of both columns is DATE (since there is no native TIME type in Oracle).